# Flutter current screen out, new in Animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I need to animate current screen A out, then screen B in. PageRouteBuilder, transition:

```
  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
    Widget child,
  ) {
    var animCurrentWidget = Tween<Offset>(begin: const Offset(0, 0), end: const Offset(0, 1))
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: const Interval(0, 0.5, curve: Curves.linear)))
        .animate(animation);
    var animNewWidget = Tween<Offset>(begin: const Offset(0, 1), end: const Offset(0, 0))
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: const Interval(0.5, 1, curve: Curves.linear)))
        .animate(animation);
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SlideTransition(position: animCurrentWidget, child: parent, transformHitTests: false),
        SlideTransition(position: animNewWidget, child: child),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Pretty simple, current screen leaves with up->down, new one goes in with sliding down->up after first one left.

But the tricky part is that you need to have access to current Widget on screen to do that, which removes use of

```
onGenerateRoute: MyCustomRouting.generateRoute
```

And forces me to work with routes in local scope of every possible screen app can have.

1. What are the best practices for tasks like that?
2. Is there a way to get current widget inside MyCustomRouting.generateRoute without going full static?
3. Is there a way to get current 'on top' widget inside other widget in the tree?